# UIKit Drawing without using Pencilkit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, drawing

I am trying to create a notes app with multiple pages for drawing in UIKit. I have tried using PencilKit but it doesn't work for me due to its lack of customizability and not being able to access much of the stroke data, not being able to detect lasso tool, and general rigidity that doesn't work with many of my other features. Are there are any good alternatives to pencilkit that I can use? How are apps like Goodnotes, Notability, or any other note app with handwriting functionality creating their pen strokes?

Answer (score 1):

The core API is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pencil_interactions/handling_input_from_apple_pencil

Those apps probably predated the pencil and wrote directly to the UITouch API, and then updated them to handle the pencil’s new cases (e.g. force and pen angle)